# oracle dbf file is normal, but cannot mount

Tags: oracle, dbf, recovery

**Things start not close oracle process when I shutdown system, after I exec startup appear error `ORA-01157` `ORA-01110`.**

[image]

**I very sure dbf file is existed, and I use dbv see the file, every thing is normal.**
[image]

**Last thing, I try offline drop those dbf, but cannot recovery them.**

Please give me some help, thank you very much!

Comment: The missing file is an UNDO tablespace file. AskTom has a good explanation of how to recover from this situation. [Check it out](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5669213349582)

Answer (score 1):

- mount your database :

  ```
  SQL> startup mount;
  ```
- Provided your database is in `NOARCHIVELOG` mode, Issue the following queries :

  ```
  SQL> select min(first_change#) min_first_change 
         from v$log V1 inner join v$logfile f on ( l.group# = f.group# );


  SQL> select change# ch_number from v$recover_file;
  ```

  If the `ch_number` is `greater` than the `min_first_change` of your logs, the datafile can be recovered.

  > If the `ch_number` is `less` than the `min_first_change` of your logs,
  >   the file cannot be recovered.
  >
  > In this case;
  >
  > **restore the most recent full backup** (and thus lose all changes to
  >   the database since) or     **recreate the tablespace**.
- Recover the datafile(`If the case in the upper yellow part isn't met`):

  ```
   SQL> recover datafile '/opt/oracle/resource/undotbs02.dbf';
  ```
- Confirm each of the logs that you are prompted for until you receive the message `Media Recovery Complete`. If you are prompted for a non-existing 
  archived log, Oracle probably needs one or more of the online logs to proceed with the recovery. Compare the sequence number referenced in the 
  `ORA-00280` message with the sequence numbers of your online logs. Then enter the full path name of one of the members of the redo group whose sequence 
  number matches the one you are being asked for. Keep entering online logs as requested until you receive the message `Media Recovery Complete` .
- If the database is at mount point, open it :

  ```
   SQL> alter database open;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If the DBF file fails to mount then check the source of DBF file, whether it is imported from other database or converted with any other tool. Generally, if the DBF file does not have a specific form then it cannot be mounted, troubleshoot Oracle DBF file by following steps
https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/File/Troubleshooting/exportpaths.htm
If the database is still causing the problem then there could be problems with other components and before mounting fix them with a professional database recovery tool like https://www.filerepairtools.com/oracle-database-recovery.html